# How to convert web-map website to mobile phone

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created simple web-map application,It works perfect on Desktop,but when I open on mobile or tablet then their is size problem.
When I open web-map in mobile then all the web-map content size are changed. I also added this html code

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no">
```

in my file but still not showing proper output.

How I convert web-map to responsive web-map.How to test it on local machine.

Comment: It should be working fine with this `meta` tag.

Comment: I added meta tag but still not working.How i check on my mobile modified version.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like that

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,target-densitydpi=high-dpi,initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
```

Comment: Can you see this link on mobile please http://geo.mes.ac.in/13_06_2017/index.html# .Two divs are overlapping in mobile window.